# How wsprintf knows the length of lpFmt string?

Tags: winapi

[`wsprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550(v=vs.85).aspx) uses [_cdecl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx) calling convention just like `printf`. The latter pops from the stack an address of null-terminated format-string. But winapi definition of `wsprintf` uses LPCTSTR type, e.g. no null at the end.

I am wondering, how the length of the LPCTSTR lpFmt being computed? I mean, the function should stop reading the format buffer at some point. And it does. And it works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it proposes a wrong statement and then asks about implementation details based on those wrong assumptions. It is not generally useful.

Comment: You right. I had to read about windows data types first. Partially I got confused because code like this worked in fasm: `cinvoke wsprintf, outputBuffer, '%d', eax` It made me think I was right about missing \0 at the end of the lpFmt-string _type_. I was wrong.

Comment: Ok, now I see: `cinvoke` macro with _'%d'_ as argument actually declares something like `tmp db '%', 'd', 0` and then pushes address of `tmp` to the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LPCTSTR for UNICODE is defined as LPCWSTR and in [msdn docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#LPCWSTR) you can read that LPCWSTR is defined as:

> A pointer to a constant null-terminated string of 16-bit Unicode
>   characters. For more information, see Character Sets Used

so wsprintf reads format until it finds L'\0' character. It is actually not written explicitly in [wsprintf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550(v=vs.85).aspx) doc.

Answer (score 1):

`LPCTSTR` *is* null-terminated. It is

```
const char*
```

or

```
const wchar_t*
```

depending on whether or not you target Unicode. But either way, it is null-terminated.

Comment: Details at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#LPCTSTR

Answer (score 0):

you are confusing many things

_cdecl defers from __stdcall by how to push arguments in the stack, it has nothing to do with NULL terminated strings.

then LPCTSTR, LPSTR, char* wchar *, all are NULL terminated strings (the difference is that some of them are Unicode while others as Ansi

other type of string that micrsoft uses it (and which is not mentioned here)  is BSTR, BSTR is not a terminated string, its len is strored in buff[-1]; (BSTR is a string of 16bits chars, as Unicode)